# stm32 does not exit sleep

Tags: stm32, sleep, hal

When trying to implement sleep mode it appears the code enters and exits sleep mode once and then gets stuck in sleep mode after and will not wake back up. I posted some code below of what I believe affects the sleep function. I want the code to sleep, wake up due to interrupt and perform function, and then go back to sleep until next interrupt. Using STM32L476VG and True Studio

```
   void init_All(void){
       MICRO_SPI_Init();
       init_wireless();
       FLASH_INIT();
       power_init();
       enter_sleep();
}

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();


  /* Configure the system clock */

  SystemClock_Config();


  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI3_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  MX_UART4_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();

  __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart4, UART_IT_RXNE);      //Enables Receive Interrupt
    init_All();
    done=1;
    while(1){
     }

}


static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
/* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = MICRO_CS;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(MICRO_CS_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init ERB Clock Select EXTI12*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI2_IRQn, 1, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI2_IRQn);
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)

{

    if (GPIO_Pin==MICRO_CS)
    {
    HAL_ResumeTick();
    if (done==1){
        sendDataState();
    }

     enter_sleep();
    }

}

void power_init(void)

{

      /* Disable Prefetch Buffer */

      __HAL_FLASH_PREFETCH_BUFFER_DISABLE();



      /* Reset all RCC Sleep and Stop modes register to */

      /* improve power consumption                      */

      RCC->AHB1SMENR  = 0x0;

      RCC->AHB2SMENR  = 0x0;

      RCC->AHB3SMENR  = 0x0;



      RCC->APB1SMENR1 = 0x0;

      RCC->APB1SMENR2 = 0x0;

      RCC->APB2SMENR  = 0x0;



        /* Configure the system Power */

        SystemPower_Config();

}

/**

  * @brief  System Power Configuration

  * @retval None

  */

void SystemPower_Config(void)

{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;



      /* Set all GPIO in analog state to reduce power consumption */

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();



    GPIO_InitStructure.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;

    GPIO_InitStructure.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;

    GPIO_InitStructure.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;

    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = GPIO_PIN_All;



    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOH, &GPIO_InitStructure);



    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_DISABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_DISABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_DISABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_DISABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_DISABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_DISABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_DISABLE();



  /* Enable PWR clock */

  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();





  //Under Voltage Protection

  PWR_PVDTypeDef sConfigPVD = { 0 };



  //2.9 V under voltage

  sConfigPVD.PVDLevel =PWR_PVDLEVEL_6;

  HAL_PWR_ConfigPVD(&sConfigPVD);

  HAL_PWR_EnablePVD();

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(PVD_PVM_IRQn, 0, 0);

  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(PVD_PVM_IRQn);



}



/**

  * @brief  Enter Sleep Mode

  * @retval None

  */

void enter_sleep(void){



    /*Suspend Tick increment to prevent wakeup by Systick interrupt.

    Otherwise the Systick interrupt will wake up the device within 1ms (HAL time base)*/

    HAL_SuspendTick();



     /* Enter Sleep Mode , wake up is done once User push-button is pressed */

        HAL_PWR_EnterSLEEPMode(PWR_MAINREGULATOR_ON, PWR_SLEEPENTRY_WFI);



}
```

Comment: Simplify the program down to only what is needed to still demonstrate the problem; remove the call to sendDataState() not included in your question and make sure that was not the issue.  Do something like blip a GPIO in the ISR and verify that the interrupt can be repeatedly triggered when *not* going to sleep.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That test has already been completed and program works fine without the addition of sleep.

Comment: Add  `__HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU)` to clear the wake flags in you callback routine and see if that solves your problem.